# How to upgrade/re-encrypt PGP encrypted emails to a new key?

Tags: email, encryption, pgp, thunderbird

Scenario: Assume your PGP key pair is compromised and thus you create a new one. (Or for any other reasons, most common that your key pair is expired.)

Is there any way to re-encrypt the emails with the old key to the new key?

I am using thunderbird/enigmail so a way with these tools would be appreciated, but not necessary. Furthermore I am using gmail, so I would like to have the old emails removed from gmail and replaced with the new encrypted ones. In this context: Is that a good idea at all? Let's assume the attacker has access to the old key and the emails. When I upload the old emails with the new key, is he able to infer anything about my new key?

Comment: 1. yes, decode and re-encode. 2. yes, don't keep known-compromised stuff around longer than needed. 3. Yes, but it should still be secure enough to withstand that reveal unless you've make a fundamental mistake or have ectobytes of email.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the attacker has access to your old key and your emails, you can assume he or she has already decrypted them and has a copy of them locally. Decrypting and then encrypting them won't serve much of a purpose.

Comment: In this case yes. But the main part of the question is actually: Your key pair is expired, what do you do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a government issued PKI card, you can use MailCrypt (http://iase.disa.mil/pki-pke/Pages/tools.aspx).  It is made for situations where your certificates are expiring but you still need access to old encrypted emails.  You can re-encrypt with any certificate.

Comment: Government issued? And this tool just works with Outlook. With encryption you shouldn't use closed source processes/software.

Comment: Agreed about both limitations - it's just the only tool at all that I have seen that does this function.  I also wish that it could encrypt emails that had never been encrypted but it can't (or won't).  It will only re-encrypt emails that had been encrypted prior.

Comment: I should also correct that it isn't limited to a government issued PKI.  It is a PKI issued by a governmentally recognized organization (IdenTrust, ORC, and Symantec) (http://iase.disa.mil/pki/eca/Pages/index.aspx)